# Checking for keylogger/trojan/spyware on OS X

Tags: macos, security, osx-lion, spyware

I have enabled hidden files, ran `netstat` to observe active connections, and I am running Clamxav. Anybody know any other tricks or ideas to find anything hiding? This is a client's machine. It ppears to be fine. Just want to know if anything else I could try.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Activity Monitor app, probably in /Applications/Utilities/. Or use top in the Terminal. But if things appear fine, what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

OS X uses `launchd` to control system and user services. The `launchctl` command connects with launchd to inspect and manage daemons, agents and XPC services. See `man launchctl` and `man launchd`.

There are places where you can look for suspicious files. Applications install valid services. Malware may have installed a malicious agent or service.

Look for unusual files in these folders, especially `~/Library/LaunchAgents` because it's user-writable. `~/Library/LaunchDaemons` should not exist. If it's present, it's suspicious.

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents         User-provided agents
/Library/LaunchAgents          Administrator-provided agents
/Library/LaunchDaemons         Administrator-provided system-wide daemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents   OS X per-user agents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons  OS X system-wide daemons
```

Run `launchctl list | sort -k3` and look for unusual items.

Run `launchctl print system` for a detailed list of agents and services.

The older, legacy method before `launchd` was `cron`. Run `crontab -l` for users and for root. See `man crontab` and `man cron`.

```
$ crontab -l
crontab: no crontab for user
$ sudo su
# crontab -l
crontab: no crontab for root
# exit
```